# handlebars returning index along with data

Tags: indexing, handlebars.js

I have a helper that loops through jason data till a given value and sends the data back to the template.I also want to show at what location the data is present (the index), is there any way where in i can return the Index value along with the data?

```
 Handlebars.registerHelper('print_range', function(items,count,options) 
 {
     var out = "";
     for(var i=0, l=items.length; i<count; i++) 
     {
         out = out + options.fn(items[i]);

     }

     return out;

});

<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#print_range options "2"}}


   <h1>index</h1> // this index should correspond to i in the helper function 


   <h2>{{optionID}}{{nextID}}</h2>
   {{/print_range}}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('print_range', function(items,count,options) 


{{#print_range options "2"}}
```

Not sure 100% what you're asking, but i do see a problem in your code. You specify 3 parameters in the function, but only give it 2 in your statement call to the helper.

```
{{#print_range options "2"}}
   ^ fn name    ^items  ^ count
```

Where's the value for your options variable? In handlebars, the parameters for the function go in order after the helper name you are calling